# Looking at date range and find if the is available

Tags: postgresql, datetime, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a reservation from `Sat, 01 Dec 2018 02:45:00 UTC +00:00` to 
`Sun, 02 Dec 2018 02:45:00 UTC +00:00` but I want to search availability from `Sat, 01 Dec 2018 05:15:00 UTC +00:00` to `Sat, 01 Dec 2018 06:45:00 UTC +00:00` this is within the previous reservation obviously this reservation is impossible because its already book.

unfortunately, when I query this comes as available because it does not touch any date of the reserved date.

how can I query this returning the current reservation?

I am using rails 5 Postgres Database.

```
reserved Initial date |-------------------------| reserved final date
      search Initial Date|-----------|search final Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OVERLAPS` operator

```
..WHERE (availability_start, availability_end) 
          OVERLAPS (reservation_from, reservation_to) IS FALSE
```

[Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html)